# httpdが起動しません…

Tags: linux, apache, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Piにapache2を入れてWEBサーバにしています
今日起動したところ、apache2は起動するのですがhttpdが起動しません

> sudo service httpd start

を入力すると、

> Failed to start httpd.service: Unit httpd.service failed to load: No
>   such file or directory.

と表示されますが、どのファイルが見つかっていなくてどこに設定すればよいのでしょうか？

ちなみに、前回は自分の家のグローバルIPをURLに入力して「It Work！」の表示まで出来ました
前回シャットダウンしてから今回起動する間には全く触れていません

何か初歩的なミスをしている気がするのですが、心当たりある方あればご教授ください

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> どのファイルが見つかっていなくてどこに設定すればよいのでしょうか？

`httpd.service` というファイルが無いといってます。これはsystemdの設定ファイルで CentOS などの環境で Apache HTTPD サーバーの起動設定が書かれたものです。

お使いの環境の場合は `httpd.service` が無い代わりに `apache2.service` というファイルで設定されてると思いますので apache2 が起動できるなら httpd は気にしなくて良いです。

Answer (score 0):

情報が少なく解決になるか分かりませんが参考まで

Raspberry Pi + Apache2 と言う事は標準のRaspbian(Raspberry Pi用Debian)かと思います。
Debianの場合は、「/etc/apache2/」以下に設定ファイルがあり、「/etc/apache2/httpd.conf」 が主たる設定ファイルです。

恐らく最初の方に、DocumentRoot から始まる行があるので、その行の

```
DocumentRoot [PATH_TO_DOCROOT]
```

の部分を確認してみてください。
何も変えていなければ[/var/www/html]になってることが多いです。

Answer (score 0):

OSにRaspbianを利用しているとしてこのディストリビューションはDebianベースなのでapache httpdのサービス名はhttpdではなくapache2です．
導入時のパッケージもそうだったと思います．

```
$ sudo service apache2 status
$ nc localhost 80
GET /index.html
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
 :
```

とかしてみると確認できるかと思います．
/usr/share/doc/apache2/以下の文章も参考になると思います．